Can a 200 mAh 1C Li-ion pouch battery handle 500 mA draw spikes?
I am running a ESP8266 with a 400 mAh Li-ion pouch battery through a 3.3 V regulator.
I need a smaller battery to save space inside my device case. From my measurements, the overall current draw is around 130 mA, but according to the chip datasheet it can have current spikes bigger than 200 mA and after a google search for "esp8266 peak current" we can find values much bigger than the 200 mA. So my question is can the 200 mAh 1C battery handle these kind of spikes? Will it damage the battery or degrade it faster?

Can you provide us with a datasheet?

for the chip I have the jlc link (I believe it downloads immediately) https://wmsc.lcsc.com/wmsc/upload/file/pdf/v2/lcsc/2401121831_DOIT-ESP-12F_C19949064.pdf

for the battery, unfortunately I do not. It came from aliexpress :)

While the datasheet does not specify the peak current exactly - it says "> 200ma" a google search for esp8266 peak current yields values quite bigger than the 200, so take my 500ma with a grain of salt, but I think the question still holds - edited the question

a 1000uf cap will erase the spikes almost completely. that said, the spikes are very brief and probably won't cause issues if left as-is.

@dandavis thanks! do you recommend the 1000uf cap next to the battery or next to the chip's vdd?

as close to the MCU as it will fit.


Will it damage the battery or degrade it faster?

Damage it, not really. Degrade it faster? Yes, of course. By how much? We can't tell and it's unlikely that even the cell manufacturer knows.
Do what @dandavis suggested: add a large capacitor in parallel to source the current peaks so that the cell doesn't have to.

Without a datasheet or a pulse current rating on the battery and information on how long/often the ESP8266 will draw more than 200mA, it is impossible to 100% determine if the battery will suffer any damage over time.
The current draw of the ESP8266 is going to depend on the program and how you have things configured as well.
My suggestion is to measure the current draw of the ESP8266 over time and find out how often the current spikes and for how long. If these pulses last for less than several milliseconds and/or only occur when the device is starting, the battery you selected should work fine.
To measure this, you could use a 0.1 Ohm resistor on the ground side of the ESP8266 and measure the voltage with a scope. The voltage will be 0.013V at 130mA. ( V = I x R )
However, I'll give you some design suggestions for supplying your device with power. I'm assuming you are using a 1-cell battery (3.0V - 4.2V), which means that depending on what kind of regulator you are using, you may not even have 3.3V on the regulator output. Basic linear regulators have a dropout voltage that can be substantial (1-2V) if not using an LDO regulator (Typically 0.1V - 0.2V).
See here for more info
If you are using a 2-cell battery and a linear regulator, the circuit will not be as efficient as you might think, either.
With 3.3V out @ 130mA, and 7.4V in @ ~130mA, the efficiency is:
P_out / P_in = (3.3x0.13) / (7.4x0.13) = 429mW/962mW = 45% efficiency. (This will cut your expected battery life in half)
A linear regulator essentially regulates the voltage drop across itself so that the voltage on the load remains at the desired level. The voltage across the regulator in this case would be 7.4 - 3.3 = 4.1V @ ~130mA (The regulator uses some very small amount of current too)
4.1V x 0.130A = 533mW just being wasted, converting the voltage to 3.3V out.
A 2-cell battery of similar capacity will be roughly twice the size too, so you'll have to get a battery with ~half the capacity if you want it to be small enough.
My recommendation is to get a small buck-boost converter board made for 1S lipos. I use these in all of my battery-operated projects.
I did a quick search and found this 3.3V-5V adjustable one: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10255
If you're willing to search around more, you may even find some with built-in charging and on/off switches.

Thanks for the answer! I do have a single cell battery and I do use an LDO with a output very close to 3.3V. I will measure, once I get an oscilloscope on my hands, the current draw. For now, like @dandavis suggested, I will replace my current 100uF capacitor with a bigger 1000uF.
